# Почему js не округляет некоторые числа?

Tags: javascript, округление

Можете сказать, почему иногда js при деление выдает число с кучей знаков после запятой и 1 например `45.0000000001`, можно поинтересоваться зачем, если все числа делятся нацело?

Comment: Потому что погрешность... почитай об особенностях хранения вещественных чисел в памяти компьютера. При слабой типизации, округлять результат деления - это задача программиста.

Comment: @yar85 Я правильно понимаю, что все из-за степеней 2-ки?

Comment: Да, по сути правильно.